# Sudden appearance of Uncaught Type Error, location.reload has no method "apply"

Tags: javascript, typeerror

The JavaScript I have been working with is one I run through Tampermonkey via Chrome, that executes itself onto a web page, scanning for certain conditions, and refreshing periodically.

For whatever reason, it has suddenly stopped working, and I am met with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object location.reload(true); has no method 'apply'

My code:

```
if (condition1 <= condition2) 
{
    // some commands here
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 7500);
} else
{
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 5000);
}
```

This was functional for the longest time, but has only recently stopped working.

Comment: It sounds like something is overriding `setTimeout` and assuming you’re passing a function — which you absolutely should be! Change it to `setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true); }, 7500);`, and then try `console.log(setTimeout)` and see whether it’s still the original native function.

Answer (score 1):

Your string should probably be a function. `setTimeout` will then use that function as a callback after the given time has elapsed.

```
if (condition1 <= condition2) 
{
 /*some commands here*/
 setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); },7500);
} else
{
 setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); },5000);
}
```

Comment: Normally, if the first argument to `setTimeout` is a string, that string is evaluated. It’s bad practice, but shouldn’t break anything (especially not with that error) on its own.

Comment: @rynah - I tested that with jsFiddle and found it to be true. I guess it uses the Function() constructor? I edited my answer to remove the comment about using a string.

Comment: @Blender: It does, and it’s a very bad idea in general — but where’s `apply` in that code?